# Scala method to pretty print XML directly to a java.io.Writer (not a string)?

Tags: xml, scala

The scala.xml.XML.write method supports outputting an XML node sequence to a java.io.Writer, for example in a servlet response. However, it doesn't seem to have an option to output the XML in pretty printed format. Is there any Scala standard library function to pretty print an XML node sequence to a java.io.Writer?

Note: scala.xml.PrettyPrinter does not seem to be the answer because it only returns a string. The pretty printer would need to output directly to a java.io.Writer.

Comment: There's no such format - pretty printed XML; and there could be no generic pretty-printing. Pretty printing completely depends on the destination you're printing to (and the way tabs, line breaks, paddings, etc. should be specified there). `scala.xml.PrettyPrinter` helps, when the destination is console. In case of servlet response, just send XML as it is, and make pretty printing on the client side.

Comment: Vasil: Yes there is such a format, and we all know what it means. Let's concentrate on being constructive here: all that's needed is scala.xml.PrettyPrinter without output to java.io.Writer. It's doable: the question is just has anyone already done it. And it is entirely reasonable to want to pretty print output in the servlet while developing.

Comment: Can't you just define a function that does `out.write(prettyPrinter.format(node))`?

Comment: "It's doable" >> It's senseless. That's why no one has implemented it.

Comment: huynhjl: That outputs well-formed XML, but there is no provision for doctypes and similar (needed to trigger certain HTML rendering modes in certain browsers).

Comment: 'HTML rendering modes in certain browsers' It rather depends on the content-type.

Comment: Scala's XML support is excellent until you run into all of it's deficiencies.  [JDOM](http://www.jdom.org/) is more verbose but excellent nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

I wrote a PrettyPrinter that can directly write to a given file: [XMLPrettyPrinter](https://github.com/jmcejuela/Scala-XML-Pretty-Printer/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/jmcejuela/scala/xml/XMLPrettyPrinter.scala)

I use it in production.

Answer (score 0):

`scala.xml.PrettyPrinter.format(Node,StringBuilder)` could be abused by redirecting the `append` calls to the writer ... However, this depends heavily on the current implementation of PrettyPrinter, so this is a non-answer ;-)